# ASP.NET and HTML 5

Tags: asp.net, html

Does asp.net (not mvc) support HTML 5? I need to create HTML 5 application, but I don't want to use mvc...

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see this [HTML5 for ASP.NET Developers](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/09/01/pfcov_html5.aspx) article for some information.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use MVC, you also don't use any HTML template engine, so ASP.NET does not touch your HTML output. You can output whatever you want, for example HTML5.